# Exception thrown: 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' in mscorlib.ni.dll uwp

Tags: c#, uwp

i Go the above error and i don't know why, when i called CreateFolderAsync()

```
StorageFolder appInstalledFolder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;

StorageFolder newFolder = await appInstalledFolder.CreateFolderAsync(ClientFolder, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);


Activated   Event   Time    Duration    Thread
    Exception thrown: 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' in mscorlib.ni.dll ("Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))")   0.24s       [13604] Worker Thread
```

I have set these capabilities:

```
<Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <uap:Capability Name="removableStorage" />
  </Capabilities>
```

Where is the problem:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not use Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.You can use

```
ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
```

ApplicationData.Current have LocalFolder and LocalCache and the tempUse file or folder can put in LoacalCache and the AppData can write in LocalFolder.

If you need use the Users file or folder,you can use the FolderPicker or FilePicker to pick the folder and file.

The StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList can remember the users folder and file ,but it should use token.

You can see https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-reading-and-writing-files

Comment: i have the same problem when  await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(path)

Comment: You can use Pick and not use path.